# Cypress causing type errors in jest assertions

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress

I had been using `react-testing-library` as well as `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect`. I installed Cypress yesterday, and now I'm getting Typescript errors on all my jest matchers:

`Property 'toEqual' doesn't exist on type 'Assertion'. Did you mean 'equal'?`

It looks like it's getting the type of `expect` from the wrong assertion library or something? Also, `expect(...).to.equal(...)` doesn't even work either.

I actually tried installing `@types/jest` and yarn appears to have succeeded but it's not listed in my `package.json`'s `devDependencies`.

Here's my `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "cypress",
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I'll also mention that all my `cy` calls in my cypress tests are getting a `cy is not defined` error from ESLint.

Comment: Since Cypress v10 the [main cause](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1148921141) of the error is `./cypress.config.ts`.
Consider to try [Marcus Fonseca's answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999086/cypress-causing-type-errors-in-jest-assertions/72663546#72663546)

Answer (score 80):

I ran into this problem yesterday. It seems that what you are saying is correct, cypress and jest both declares types for `expect`. In this case the cypress declaration seem to be the one that is picked up. Here's an issue from the cypress repo regarding this:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1603

The solution mentioned in there worked for me. You need to exclude the jest spec files from in `tsconfig.json` and then declare a `tsconfig.spec.json` where they are explicitly included again.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  ...,
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  ...
}
```

With this in place, both my (angular 8) app compiles fine and I can run the jest tests without issue. Here's another example mentioned in the issue with a similar fix being implemented:

https://github.com/neiltownsley/react-typescript-cypress/pull/1/files#diff-e5e546dd2eb0351f813d63d1b39dbc48R29

NOTE 9 Mar 2023: Since **Cypress v10** the [main cause](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1148921141) of the error is `./cypress.config.ts`.
Consider to try [Marcus Fonseca's answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999086/cypress-causing-type-errors-in-jest-assertions/72663546#72663546)

Comment: Do you mean the Cypress `.spec` files?

Comment: @foakesm Sorry if it is unclear from the text above. The base `tsconfig.json` excludes the _jest_ `.spec` files, and then the `tsconfig.spec.json` (that jest uses) includes them. For this to work, we're assuming you Cypress tests are not in files named `*.spec.ts`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This also worked when dealing with the same issue between Cypress + Jasmine in an Angular workspace. Thanks!

Comment: This problem goes into Karma/Jasmine in Angular. My solution was to close all *.spec.ts files and do the exclude/include. It seems that Angular-files needs a "re-boot" to get the changes correct.

Comment: This approach has drawback with VSCODE hints. VSCODE uses typescript server, which will not work with two tsconfig files. Better approach in this case will be go with
```import { expect } from '@jest/globals';```

Comment: Works for me! I was looking for working solution between cypress component testing and jasmine unit testing in one directory.

Answer (score 77):

Anyone facing this problem in the  [github issue "New Cypress 10 global TypeScript type conflicts with Jest expect"](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1148921141) has a workaround

Fix issue by exluding `./cypress.config.ts` in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"exclude": [
  "./cypress.config.ts",
  //other exclusions that may help https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1428298264
  "node_modules",
  "cypress",
  "**/*.cy.tsx"
]
```

From cypress developer:

> We didn't change our globals very much for v10. For all the cases I reproduced, it was fixed by adding ./cypress.config.ts to the tsconfig.exclude property. Since the cypress.config.ts is being included in the type checking, it is loading the cypress types which is polluting your jest tests.

Comment: This! And I also had to "exclude" all my cypress test files in my eslint config, because those files also include "cypress" which pollutes the jest typings.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find name 'cy'.`

Comment: I also get the "Cannot find name 'cy' in all my cypress test now.

Answer (score 69):

There is an official Cypress repo that shows how to fix this exact problem https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example

I wasn't able to get that method to work in one of my projects, so I am using this as a workaround:

```js
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';
```

Comment: I have followed the official Cypress repo. Thanks for the link.

Comment: This was the only thing working for me, it would be nice to have it solved properly though :/.

Comment: After exhausting my entire list of expletives, the link to the cypress-and-jest-typescript-example in the official Cypress repo referenced in this answer finally worked for my Angular 15 + Cypress 12 project. The only difference was in tsconfig.json, where I changed the "exclude" to ["src/*.spec.ts"]

Comment: Same, none of the config shenanigans worked as it was importing cypress straight from node_modules even if there was no cypress folder with test specs. But this is madness and not a real solution.

Answer (score 27):

Finally I found the solution!
Just add `"cypress"` to the `exclude` property of your main `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  ...YOUR_CONFIGS,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...YOUR_CONFIGS,
    "typeRoots": [ // THIS TO GET ALL THE TYPES
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": ["cypress"], 
}
```

You should add also another `tsconfig.json` for your cypress tests. You can create a cypress folder and add that `tsconfig.json` there.
The following is my Cypress `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion with the `exclude:[cypress]`, that did the trick for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also exclude cypress.config.ts if you have that as well.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me in my tsconfig.json

I had to add

```
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
```

Complete code here

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
    "esModuleInterop" : true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That was the key for me too. adding `src/**` in the root `tsconfig.json` solved it after looking at the other settings in the example repo: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example.

Answer (score 13):

There are several cases that cause this issue.
In my case, It was fixed by adding ./cypress.config.ts to the tsconfig.exclude property. Since the cypress.config.ts is being included in the type checking, it is loading the cypress types which is polluting your jest tests.
I believe it will help you if you are using typscript for cypress configuration.

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to keep it included but not cause that issue.

Comment: Okay, seems like this is the only possible solution since Cypress v10. They suggest excluding `cypress.config.ts` and including it in the `<root>/cypress/tsconfig.ts` (if you're using separated tsconfig for Cypress ofc) instead.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059

Answer (score 12):

There are three steps to make it disappear.

1. In your `/cypress/` directory add `tsconfig.json`.
2. Paste the following content as [in this example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example/blob/master/cypress/tsconfig.json):

   ```
   {
       "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
       "compilerOptions": {
          "noEmit": true,
          "types": ["cypress"]
       },
       "include": [
           "../node_modules/cypress",
           "./**/*.ts"
       ]
   }
   ```
3. In your **original** `tsconfig.json` add

   ```
   {
     ...
     "exclude": ["cypress"]
     ...
    }
   ```

to the top level configuration. That's it.

**A few extra notes:**

1. If your `cypress/tsconfig.json` complains about `include, exclude` you may need to overwrite their values as they are inherited from the original file. In my case adding

   ```
   "exclude": [],
   ```

   ...has solved the problem.
2. May be trivial but remember to use `.ts` extension to files for your spec from now on.

Comment: Adding `"exclude": []` solved my issue too, excellent suggestion

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way for solving this issue is to add this line to tsconfig.json:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
```

I am attaching my tsconfig file for better understanding. You can see the addition in lines 3-5.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me in an Ionic app with jasmine/cypress. I needed to close Visual Studio Code and reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem and after trying the above options, a combination two solutions worked. Adding below to test file

```
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';.
```

and this one to tsconfig.json(included to stop jest @types errors)

```
{ "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ] 
}
```

Comment: It works fine but I didn't have to update may tsconfig.sjon

Answer (score 2):

In my case it helps the only one thing: adding `"types": ["jest"]` to `"compilerOptions"`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["jest"],
   ...
  },     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `tsconfig.json` add the following,

```
"exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]
```

In `tsconfig.spec.json` add the following

```
"exclude": [""],
```

"include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]

Answer (score 1):

Since I used `ng add @cypress/schematic` to set up Cypress, my `cypress/tsconfig.json` file had this line in it:

```json
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
```

`./tsconfig.json` was trying to exclude the same files that `./cypress/tsconfig.json` was trying to include, which created the conflict. To solve the problem:

1. Remove `"extends": "../tsconfig.json"` from `cypress/tsconfig.json`
2. Add `"include": ["**/*.cy.ts"]` to `cypress/tsconfig.json`
3. Per [Marcus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72663546/1805453), to `./tsconfig.json`, add:

```json
"exclude": [
  "./cypress.config.ts",
  "node_modules",
  "cypress"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem originated with the use of @testing-library/cypress. According to the [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/#with-typescript) you need to add the below to your `tsconfig.json` and that causes the problem.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"]
  }
}
```

Creating a `./cypress/tsconfig.json` with the above instead of having it in `./tsconfig.json` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today also - what caused it was moving my Cypress folder from / to src/test. I moved it back to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Next.js app. This tsconfig.json works for me:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the answers above, I preferred to just rename the Cypress files to [their current naming convention](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Execution), so eslint doesn't consider them Jest files in the first place.

### Here's the process I used to make the change.

---

**1. Rename all tests:**

`My-Cypress-Test.spec.js` becomes `My-Cypress-Test.cy.js`

**WARNING:** THIS IS A RECURSIVE COMMAND, SO ANY MATCHING FILES IN ANY SUBDIRECTORY WILL BE AFFECTED

```
find ./**/cypress/** -name '*.spec.js' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.spec.js}.cy.js"' '{}' \;
```

*This command assumes that your cypress tests are in the default folder name "cypress".*

If that's not the case, modify the command below to reflect that, or just cd to your cypress test directory and run it against `./`

---

**2. Update your Cypress config to match against the new file extensions (if needed)**

In `cypress.config.js`:

replace `specPattern: "./cypress/integration/**/**/*.spec.js",`

with
`specPattern: "./cypress/integration/**/**/*.cy.js",`

---

**3. (Optional): Ensure git treats this process as a rename**

I've noticed that git tends to consider the old file as deleted and the newly renamed file as a new file, which can break your file history / git blame, etc.

I fix this by simply running `git add .` in any parent directory of the renamed files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the solution is as easy as it sounds: just follow the official tutorial: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfigjson

1. Do not add anything related to cypress in your root `tsconfig`
2. Create new `tsconfig` in cypress folder as shown in the tutorial (copy-paste)
3. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can find out about the conflict between Jest and Cypress in the link to the documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Clashing-types-with-Jest

Example of a proposed solution:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In Angular project I was using Jasmine for UT and Cypress for e2e but I wanted to use component testing too. I had got problem with Jasmine and Mocha typings. I solved problem with Typescript `references` in `tsconfig.json`.

I was based on [Github comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1447863585)

tsconfig.json (part)

```
"include": ["src"],
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" }, { "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json" }, { "path": "./tsconfig.cy.json" }]
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "types": ["jasmine"],
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true
},
"files": ["testing/jest-global-mocks.ts"],
"include": ["app/**/*.spec.ts"],
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true
},
"include": ["src", "cypress", "node_modules/cypress"],
"exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with cypress + jasmine and nothing would help.

Finally, I ended with copying the jasmine `expect` declaration and putting it in a new file `/test/global.d.ts`:

```
declare function expect<T>(actual: T): jasmine.Matchers<T>;
```

Might be worth mentioning that in my `tsconfig.json` the folder is explicitly included as follows:

```
{
    "include": ["test/**/*", ...]
}
```

This caused yet another shadowing of the dreaded cypress and silenced the compilator.