# Cypress: Clashing types with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress

I am facing the problem the types in Cypress and Jest clashing (such as "expect").

example.spec.ts

```
expect(value).toBe(0) // Property 'toBe' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.
```

I edited tsconfig.json in the following way, but it did not solve.

- Remove "cypress" from "types" property
- [Exclude the jest spec files from in tsconfig.json and declare another tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999086/cypress-causing-type-errors-in-jest-assertions)
- [Exclude the jest spec files from in tsconfig.json and add tsconfig in cypress directory](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example)

Here's my `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@types/node",
      "nuxt-i18n",
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem with the following:

./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,
    ...
  },
  "exclude": ["cypress/**/*"]
}
```

./cypress/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": false
  },
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/cypress"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was enough to exclude the Cypress configuration file name in the project' `tsconfig.json`. I did not need to put "isolatedModules" flag.

Example:

```
  "exclude": [
    ...
    "cypress.config.ts",
    ...
  ]
```

It works in a project with webpack, jest, React Testing Library (with extensions) and Cypress mixed together.

Note: if your Webpack uses a different `tsconfig.json` make sure you exclude the file there too. Otherwise, you will not see any error in IDE but you will see them whilst making a build.

Comment: This did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue of type conflicts between cypress and jest. Most accounts have detected that the problem started occurring from cypress v10.x onward.

The *following links* corroborate the OP's own answer, suggesting the exclusion of `cypress.config.ts` from `tsconfig.json`. It may or may not be a workaround, however it has worked for me as well.

**Link 1**: *https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059*

**Link 2**: *https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/863*

*It should be noted that the tests executed successfully despite the type clash, for me, despite not having yet excluded cypress from `tsconfig.json`.*

If your own answer has solved your issue, then you can mark it as answered and close it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest , in the parent `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": ["jest"]. // or ["jasmine", "jasmine-expect"], depends on setup
"exclude": [
    "cypress/**/*.ts",
    "cypress.config.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress*/*.ts"
  ]
```

Then, in the  `cypress/tsconfig.json` :

```
"types": ["cypress", "chai"],
"include": [
    "../cypress/**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.config.ts",
    "../node_modules/cypress/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

NOTE: my project also has a `tsconfig.spec.json`.