# Cypress causes: Property 'each' does not exist on type 'TestFunction'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, dependencies, cypress

We have introduced cypress 9.3.1 in our project for e2e test. Now we face the problem that our existing jest test don't compile in the CI.

The following error occures for all parameterized tests:

```
Property 'each' does not exist on type 'TestFunction'.
       it.each<TestCase>([
```

**Question**: How to fix it?

---

What we tried and did't work:

- Adding `import { it } from '@jest/globals'` to every test. We where able to fix a similar problem (*Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'*) by adding `import { expect } from '@jest/globals'` to every test. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65153905
- Adding a project wide exclusion for cypress globals, by adding `"exclude": ["cypress/global.d.ts"]` to the `tsconfig.spec.json`

Comment: Just for others looking at this problem: Adding `import { it } from '@jest/globals'` did work for us. As we are additionally using jasmine in this project, the jasmine type definitions where loaded here by default.

Comment: @CodeMonkey1770, thank you! 
Also, other imports like the below resolved similar issues: import { test, describe } from '@jest/globals';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the tsconfig.json as described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json) (see @JRJurman answer) but that doesn't worked in our project.

Now we are using the [cypress-each](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-each) plugin, developed by one of the cypress contributors.

```
npm i -D cypress-each
```

usage:

```
import 'cypress-each'

// create a separate test for each selector
const selectors = ['header', 'footer', '.new-todo']
it.each(selectors)('element %s is visible', (selector) => {
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.get(selector).should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: link "here" is broken

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim O.M.G! I fixed it for U.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this problem as well, it turned out a conflicting type definition from mocha was included in our `tsconfig.json`. Make sure that you aren't loading Mocha's type definitions.

Edit: what we ended up needing to do was creating a separate tsconfig.json for our cypress tests, as described here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json